# Debugging multi-site web applications in Visual Studio on Windows 8.1

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-8.5

I have a multi site Azure based web application. One site contains the web pages (with the view functionality driven through jQuery, Raphaël, and HTML) and a thin WCF service. The second site contains a more functional WCF service which in turn calls the data objects that call the database. We stopped development on the site a few years ago but it is still live for the few people who still enjoy using it.

Yesterday I had to fix an cross-site scripting vulnerability someone had reported on the site.

I was alarmed to find that I can no longer run the sites on my local machine under Visual Studio to test and debug any changes before deploying them to Azure.

Because of the interaction between the two WCF sites I had the local debugging set up as follows:

1. In the Internet Information Services Manager tool (InetMgr) I add additional websites with their physical path set to the location of the source code in the TFS local path on my machine.
2. I edit the host name in the site's binding to mimic the Azure location, i.e. the main site is projname.cloudapp.net:80 on Azure and projnamelocal.cloudapp.net:80 in my local IIS and the data WCF site is projname-wcf.cloudapp.net:8080 on Azure and projname-wcflocal.cloudapp.net:8080 in my local IIS. (N.B. The main site has a HTTPS binding too.)
3. I edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to include the lines

   `127.0.0.1  projnamelocal.cloudapp.net`

   `127.0.0.1  projname-wcflocal.cloudapp.net`
4. In Visual Studio I edit the web properties for the main site's project so that it uses the local IIS and project URL http://projname.cloudapp.net/ and I have a switch (in the code to say whether to call the local WCF or the live Azure one.

In the past when the project was under active development this set-up worked fine for locally testing and debugging. Yesterday it failed, one one machine http://projnamelocal.cloudapp.net/ gave a 503 error on another a 404. (N.B. I can ping each URL from the command line so the hosts redirect is working.) Visual Studio complains that it is "unable to start debugging on the web server" and that it "could not start ASP.NET debugging".

I've tried [all the suggestions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28vs.debug.error.http%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) and some:

- Running without debugging
- Running Visual Studio as administrator (I was already)
- Re-registering ASP
- Changing the app pool
- Giving everyone full permissions to the code directory
- Running as my own domain account that is an admin on the local machine
- Changing IE to not auto-detect proxies
- Adding the sites to IE's list of trusted sites
- Turning off IE's protected mode
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Restarting the PC
- Restarting the PC again

How should I set-up this style of running, testing, and debugging local sites work in IIS under Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I had forgotten to go to Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > .Net Framework 4.5 Advanced Services > WCF Services > HTTP Activation

Now that I have that installed the local sites start